# How to fetch records that have an alternate entry

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, group-by

I need some help to fetch records having alternate set of entries associated with Unique value(ex: user_id)

[image]

> I want output to be only (1111,2222,3333)

**Here is the scenario:**
user_id 1111 attended .net course from 2005-01-01 to 2006-12-31

he later attended java from 2007-01-01 to 2009-12-31
he later came back to .net

so i want to retrieve these kind of user_id's

user_id 4444 should not be in the output, because there is no alternative courses.

> UPDATE: 4444 started his Java course from 2007 to 2009 he again
> attended Java from 2010 - 2012 Later he attended .net but never came
> back to Java so he must be excluded from output

*If **Group by** is used, it will consider records irrespective of alternate course name.
We can create a procedure to accomplish this by looping and comparing the alternate course name but i want to know if a query can do this?*

Comment: I'm not understanding why 4444 shouldn't be in the resultset.  Can you explain how you're defining an "alternative course?"

Comment: I just updated the reason.

Comment: What if the periods of two courses overlap, 2nd starts before the 1st ends?

Comment: @dnoeth Exactly this is what happened while migrating data(Overlap of dates happened) so we are about to correct that by taking data from the primary Source.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use two `INNER JOIN` operations:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 
   ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.id < t2.id AND t1.course_name <> t2.course_name
INNER JOIN mytable AS t3
   ON t2.user_id = t3.user_id AND t2.id < t3.id AND t1.course_name = t3.course_name
```

I assume that `id` is an auto-increment field that reflects the order the rows have been inserted in the DB. Otherwise, you should use a date field in its place.

Comment: Good answer.  I would select distinct user_id, since it's possible that a user could bounce back and forth several times and your result set would get duplicates.

Comment: @StanShaw Good catch. Updated. Thank you very much.

Comment: Sorry actually id will not be considered, I created a replica of my current situation with some sample data. In real-time id will not be in incremental format. Good Logic thank you. Will run this

Comment: @Ramaraju.d This should not be a problem, since you can use `end_date` at its place

Comment: @Ramaraju.d If you have it in your powers, I would add an auto-incrementing ID field to this table.  I would suggest having one for almost every table you create.  Only exception I can think of is a "join table" where all of the columns are foreign keys - and there are circumstances when it would be helpful there, as well.

Comment: Yes, what if there is a NULL in place of End_date? or i can simply put some dummy future date using a decode right?

Comment: @Ramaraju.d How can you tell then that courses are alternating? Use `start_date` instead?

Comment: @StanShaw unfortunately i dont have access to execute DDL, DML commands. It has thousands of data out of which i have to select records having above scenario

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos yes considering start_date or end_dates should do the trick. I have to check.

Comment: Using Start_Date should avoid any issues with end date, and unless the person is simultaneously taking multiple courses, it's a non-issue.  If you don't have access to the DB, talk to your DBA and suggest adding auto-incrementing ID fields to tables.  Performance is better, indexing is better, and it makes a great PK.  \

Comment: Sure i will @StanShaw and GiorgosBetsos. Thanks for the idea, i am sure i got a good info from you Thank you. i will test and accept this

Answer (score 1):

Same as Girogos Betsos' answer, only with select distinct to prevent duplicates.

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM mytable AS t1
INNER JOIN mytable AS t2 
   ON t1.user_id = t2.user_id AND t1.Start_Date < t2.Start_Date AND 
      t1.course_name <> t2.course_name
INNER JOIN mytable AS t3
   ON t2.user_id = t3.user_id AND t2.Start_Date < t3.Start_Date AND 
      t1.course_name = t3.course_name
```

EDIT: Using Start_Date since the answer has been updated and IDs are not necessarily sequential.

Answer (score 1):

This is a version utilizing Windowed Aggregate Fuctions instead of multiple self joins:

```
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM
 (
   SELECT user_id
      ,course_name
      ,start_date
      ,RANK() -- number all courses 
       OVER (PARTITION BY user_id
             ORDER BY start_date)
       -
       RANK() -- number each course
       OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, course_name
             ORDER BY start_date) AS x
   FROM tab
 ) dt
GROUP BY user_id, course_name
HAVING MIN(x) <> MAX(x) -- same course but another inbetween
```

If a user has a course multiple times in a series that `x` will stay the same, if there was another course inbetween it will change:

```
java     1  -  1 = 0
java     2  -  2 = 0  <--- min
.net     3  -  1 = 2
java     4  -  3 = 1  <--- max

java     1  -  1 = 0
java     2  -  2 = 0  
.net     3  -  1 = 2
.net     4  -  2 = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a single table scan and does not rely on `GROUP BY`:

```
WITH table_name ( user_id, start_date, end_date, course_name, id ) AS (
  SELECT 1111, DATE '2005-01-01', DATE '2006-12-31', '.net',  1 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111, DATE '2007-01-01', DATE '2009-12-31', 'java',  2 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 1111, DATE '2010-01-01', DATE '2020-12-31', '.net',  3 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, DATE '2005-01-01', DATE '2006-12-31', 'java',  4 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, DATE '2007-01-01', DATE '2008-12-31', '.net',  5 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, DATE '2009-01-01', DATE '2012-12-31', '.net',  6 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 2222, DATE '2013-01-01', DATE '2016-12-31', 'java',  7 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333, DATE '2005-01-01', DATE '2007-12-31', 'java',  8 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333, DATE '2007-01-01', DATE '2008-12-31', '.net',  9 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333, DATE '2009-01-01', DATE '2013-12-31', 'java', 10 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 3333, DATE '2014-01-01', DATE '2016-12-31', '.net', 11 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444, DATE '2007-01-01', DATE '2009-12-31', 'java', 12 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444, DATE '2010-01-01', DATE '2012-12-31', 'java', 13 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444, DATE '2013-01-01', DATE '2015-12-31', '.net', 14 FROM DUAL UNION ALL
  SELECT 4444, DATE '2016-01-01', DATE '2016-12-31', '.net', 15 FROM DUAL
)
SELECT DISTINCT user_id
FROM   (
  SELECT user_id,
         LEAD( course_name )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id, course_name ORDER BY start_date )
           AS next_same_course,
         LEAD( course_name )
           OVER ( PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY start_date )
           AS next_course
  FROM   table_name
)
WHERE  next_same_course IS NOT NULL
AND    next_course <> next_same_course;
```